ISKCON preaches that Balarama is the first expansion of Sri Krishna
ISKCON preaches that Balarama is the first expansion of Sri Krishna. Which scriptures suggest the same thing?

Brahma Samhita speaks about expansion of creation into spritual and material realms.
goloka-nāmni nija-dhāmni tale ca tasya
devi maheśa-hari-dhāmasu teṣu teṣu
te te prabhāva-nicayā vihitāś ca yena
govindam ādi-puruṣaṁ tam ahaṁ bhajāmi
Shrimad Bhagwadtam speaks about expansion of Lord Sri Krishna into various forms.
Lord Balrama is the first expansion of internal potency of Sri Krishna and Lord Balram is in the seva Bhava.
Shrimati Radha Rani is also the expansion of the internal potency of Lord Sri Krishna but She is the ahladini Shakti in Prema bhava.
Shankarshan is the expansion of Lord Balrama. Shesha Naga is the expansion of Lord Shankarshan.

Hare Krsna. Thanks for your response. But can you state exact verses which mention that Balaram is the first expansion of Krsna.
